# use IN clause and Like in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-like

I want to select some data in sql express by IN clause and LIKE but no row returned.
my code is here :

```
SELECT        PointId, PointTitleId, PointTitleName, PointTitleContentText
FROM          PointsTitlesData
WHERE        (PointTitleContentText LIKE '%' + @SearchingClause + '%') 
             AND (PointId IN ('2','3'))
```

above code don't return any data but when i use only LIKE code return data.

```
SELECT        PointId, PointTitleId, PointTitleName, PointTitleContentText
FROM          PointsTitlesData
WHERE        (PointTitleContentText LIKE '%' + @SearchingClause + '%')
```

how can i use both IN and LIKE?
Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you have records that meet the criteria of the `IN`?

Comment: Well... does the table *have* any value that is like your search clause  *and* the point id is 2 or 3?

Comment: Wanna bet that [select isn't broken](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips)?

Comment: Can you show us the data from your table where PointId is 2 and 3. Also, table schema for PointsTitlesData table and version of the SQL Server are you using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate your scenario with the script below

```
Declare @SearchingClause nvarchar(20);

Create table PointsTitlesData (Pointid int, PointTitleContentText nvarchar(20));

insert into PointsTitlesData (Pointid, PointTitleContentText)
values ( 1, 'aaamypoint1aaa'), (2, 'bbbmypoint2bbb'),(3,'cccmypoint3ccc');

Set @SearchingClause = 'mypoint2';

SELECT        PointId, PointTitleContentText 
FROM          PointsTitlesData 
WHERE        (PointTitleContentText LIKE '%' + @SearchingClause + '%')  
         AND (PointId IN ('2','3')) 

-- above code don't return any data but when i use only LIKE code return data.

SELECT        PointId, PointTitleContentText 
FROM          PointsTitlesData 
WHERE        (PointTitleContentText LIKE '%' + @SearchingClause + '%')
```

I got a result for both queries so it looks like you have a data issue.
Have you tried

```
SELECT PointId from PointsTitlesData where ((PointId = 2) or (PointId = 3))
```

to check the data is there.

Regards
Jude

Answer (score 0):

probably drop the quotes:

'2','3'  should be 2,3

Comment: I use **2,3** but no data return yet.

Comment: then it must be a data issue.  there must be a record that matches both these criteria at the same time

Comment: the code is correct. problem is from janus checked combobox. thanks.

Comment: @1mohammadi.ir What does "problem is from janus checked combobox" mean?  If it is fixed then update or delete the post so people don't spend time trying to answer it.